# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React with Typescript.

I am passing `id` as a prop to my button component. Still getting the mentioned error on `e.target.id`

```
  function handleButtonClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
     someOperation(e.target.id)
  }
```

React: `18.0.0`

Typescript: `4.7.4`

Comment: share the  stackblitz/jsfiddle of this

Comment: Please try to add a second generic param,  MouseEvent

React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent> 
And yes, if you could share in some playground, would be much more help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your Button Element

```
  function handleButtonClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    someOperation(target.id);
  }
```

If you want to use properties such as `id`, `name` that exist on HTML Elements you can also do.

```
const target = e.target as Element;
```

But note to `type` the exact element if you use properties specific to an element like `value` for Input

```
const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `target` with `currentTarget`

```
function handleButtonClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  someOperation(e.currentTarget.id)
}
```

From the [Type definitions for React 18.0](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts):

**currentTarget** - a reference to the element on which the event listener is registered.

**target** - a reference to the element from which the event was originally dispatched.
This might be a child element to the element on which the event listener is registered.